# Understanding the intuition behind recursive merge sort procedure

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm confused on the following output for the following code:

```
def msort3(x):
    print("splitting:",x)
    result = []
    if len(x) < 2:
        print("merging:",x)
        return x

    mid = int(len(x) / 2)
    y = msort3(x[:mid])
    print(y)
    z = msort3(x[mid:])  ## this will be run when x is 87
    print(z)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(y) and j < len(z):
        if y[i] > z[j]:
            result.append(z[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            result.append(y[i])
            i += 1
    result += y[i:]
    result += z[j:]
    print("result is ", result)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
     print("hi", msort3([17,87,6,22]))
```

Some of the output is:

```
splitting: [17, 87, 6, 22]
splitting: [17, 87]
splitting: [17]
merging: [17]
[17]
splitting: [87]
merging: [87]
[87]
result is  [17, 87]
[17, 87]
splitting: [6, 22]
```

Now how did it read `[6, 22]`? I thought by then the recursion calls are already done when we got `result = [ 17,87]`.

Please help, I'm very confused and already tracked the code here http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the code and your behavior... but that much is obvious since an application behave like its code dictate it to do.. which means it's pretty hard to answer that kind of question. --- All I can say for now is that `result is [17, 87]` is printed inside `y = msort3(x[:mid])` of your first call, so of course the following is `z = msort3(x[mid:])` of that same call, two lines after.

Comment: Btw the behavior is perfectly fine if [6, 22] is read.

Answer (score 0):

That's working normally; the `result is  [17, 87]` print you're seeing is an intermediate result of a child call, not the final result. Recursion works by breaking the problem into smaller chunks and computing sub-results for these sub-problems, then passing the results back through the call stack towards the original caller, merging results of the sub-problems along the way.

Adding indentation to the recursion can help illustrate the process:

```
[17, 87, 6, 22] <-- split
    [17, 87] <-- split
        [17]
        [87]
    [6, 22] <-- split
        [6]
        [22]
```

On the way down, the `[17, 87]` array will be entirely examined and merged before `[6, 22]` is examined and merged. On the way back up the call stack:

```
        [17]
        [87]
    [17, 87] <-- merge
        [6]
        [22]
    [6, 22] <-- merge
[6, 17, 22, 87] <-- merge
```

Here, `[17, 87]` waits for the `[6, 22]` call to resolve completely, and the remaining `[6, 17, 22, 87]` merge is at depth 0 and is the final result.

Your example may also be confusing because the sub arrays `[17, 87]` and `[6, 22]` are already sorted, so the only merge that has any consequence is at depth 0 between `[17, 87]` and `[6, 22]`. I recommend trying some different values to see if that helps make it click.

Using the indentation trick to help "see" the recursion can be done by adding a `depth` parameter (I also shortened your code a bit for space/ease of reading although it's less efficient -- in an actual implementation, it's better to use indices than `.pop(0)` and slices):

```
def msort3(x, depth=0):
    if len(x) < 2: 
        print(" " * depth + "single:", x)
        return x

    print(" " * depth + "splitting:", x)
    mid = len(x) // 2
    l = msort3(x[:mid], depth + 4)
    r = msort3(x[mid:], depth + 4)
    result = []

    while l and r:
        if l[0] < r[0]:
            result.append(l.pop(0))
        else:
            result.append(r.pop(0))

    result += l + r
    print(" " * depth + "merged:", result)
    return result

print("\ndone:", msort3([17, 87, 6, 22]))
```

Output:

```
splitting: [17, 87, 6, 22]
    splitting: [17, 87]
        single: [17]
        single: [87]
    merged: [17, 87]
    splitting: [6, 22]
        single: [6]
        single: [22]
    merged: [6, 22]
merged: [6, 17, 22, 87]

done: [6, 17, 22, 87]
```

Comment: I'm just still a little bit confused about the recursion process.

Answer (score 0):

SO I tried to write a stack like following:

```
We need to merge sort: [17,87,6,22]
```

to do that, `we need to merge sort [ 17,87]`
To do that, `we need to merge sort [17]`

We got a base case here, and the merge sort of `[17] is 17`

then we go back, and we do the merge sort of `[87]`

I guess I'm still confused on after the sorting those two values, how come it goes again and the two functions of mergesort being called again for the other values?
I would assume by the end of merging sort of [87] and 17. The execution will end.

I got the stack written and I can see it still needs that sort merge the whole list, but how it maintains the values of left and right for each time the function is being called. I'm confused about the execution