# Recursion of merge sort algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I started learning python a few days back and I was trying to solve sorting algorithms. I recently started with merge sort algorithm. A typical merge sort program in python (as far as I know) includes a merge function and a mergesort function. The following lines are common in all of the programs I have seen:

```
left = mergesort(left)
right = mergesort(right)
merge(left, right)
```

For example in this code:

```
def divide_arr(a):    #same as mergesort function
    l = len(a)
    if l <= 1: return a
    left = a[0:int(l/2)]
    right = a[int(l/2):l]
    left = divide_arr(left)
    right = divide_arr(right)
    return merge(left, right, a)

def merge(left, right, arr):
    pl, pr, pa = 0, 0, 0
    while pl <len(left) and pr < len(right):
        if left[pl] <= right[pr]:
            arr[pa] = left[pl]
            pa += 1
            pl += 1
        elif left[pl] > right[pr]:
            arr[pa] = right[pr]
            pa += 1
            pr += 1
    while pl < len(left):
        arr[pa] = left[pl]
        pa += 1
        pl += 1
    while pr < len(right):
        arr[pa] = right[pr]
        pa += 1
        pr += 1
    return arr
```

I am really unsure how the compiler interprets these lines.

Let's take an array [4,3,2,1]. So when I call mergesort, first Left array becomes = [4,3] and right = [2,1]

Now when I recursively call mergesort for left array, I should be finally getting left = [4] and after that I call it for right array which should become = [1]

So, I should be left with merging [4] and [1] and it should return [1,4] as the final sorted array. However, this is not the case and the code indeed returns the correct sorted array.

Is there a different way in which the compiler interprets this recursive code? Or am I wrong with something I wrote above?

PS: I know similar questions have been answered here, but they don't deal with these specific lines of the code, but rather provide a general idea of merge sort

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code is missing the context of the particular implementation.

Comment: Also, you are incorrect about your sources: *many* sites walk through the detailed mechanics of merge sort.  You can do this yourself by inserting strategic `print` statements, a debugging technique you will use a *lot* as a programmer.  Been there, done that, `print`ed the t-shirt ... :-)

Comment: I don't think Python's compiler is relevant here (translating into bytecode). You're probably thinking of the interpreter that executes the bytecode. There are plenty of explanations of mergesort [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691153/understanding-the-intuition-behind-recursive-merge-sort-procedure/51691256#51691256) and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: If context is the only reason for downvotes, I'll add the complete code I wrote yesterday, I did't add it just because the question would get unnecessarily lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is executed line by line. A function call pauses the execution of the current function and waits for the called function to return. When a function is called recursively (even if it's indirectly, where `a` calls `b` and `b` calls `a`), you basically get a "new copy" of the function, with its own local variables and its own independent execution. In your example, the following is the order of the calls. Indentation shows that the function is being called by the function at the outer level (which will wait for it to return). Note that `return` isn't a function; instead, it stops the function that it is inside. I'm assuming that what happens at the end of `mergesort` is that it returns the result of `merge`.

```
mergesort([4, 3, 2, 1])
  mergesort([4, 3])
    mergesort([4])
      return [4] to mergesort([4, 3])
    mergesort([3])
      return [3] to mergesort([4, 3])
    merge([4], [3])
      return [3, 4] to mergesort([4, 3])
    return [3, 4] to mergesort([4, 3, 2, 1])
  mergesort([2, 1])
    exercise: figure out the rest :-)
```